# Set "experimentalDecorators" VS2013 website solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, angular

I'm trying to add typescript (and Angular 2) to my website solution.  On every exported class definition I am seeing the error: "Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning."

I've searched all over and every solution says to change the csproj/vbproj file to enable experiment decorators, but website solutions do not have a project file. What do I need to do to get this warning to go away?

NOTE: I think this error is preventing dependency injection from working correctly so I would like to resolve it to eliminate it as a factor for my other problem.

Comment: If your using VS 2013, then you might be using older TypeScript version. Its good to update VS with latest version of TS. In this way you can move ahead of solving it

Comment: I have TS 1.8.5 installed but a tsc -v from the visual studio command prompt said I have 1.0.3.  I went ahead and downloaded VS2015 and the "experimentalDecorators" issue went way, but dependency injection still isn't working. So it seems like my main issue is not caused by that error.